# Show input over keyboard

Tags: ios, react-native

Like on the YouTube and Facebook app, I try to implement an input that is shown over the keyboard if it gets focussed. The normal behavior is that the keyboard overlays the input. My first idea was to change the position of the input to 'fixed' when it gets focussed, but 'fixed' isn't available on React Native. Is there any other way to lay the element above the keyboard if it has focus?

[image: Facebook keyboard input]

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the position of your input according to keyboard height when it's open.

[This project](https://github.com/Andr3wHur5t/react-native-keyboard-spacer) provides a readymade component to put in the bottom of your view that will size itself to the size of the keyboard whenever it's visible, it works great on android and ios.

Comment: It doesn't work in our project. Our input is within a ScrollView.

Comment: In this case, you can put the spacer after the ScrollView, and it should take everything up. If there is a chance the input will be on the upper part of the screen then you might need to do more adjustments, but you said that having 'fixed' positioning would have helped you, so I assume that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

plz use this addObserver for keybord show and hide in viewwill apperar

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(KeyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(KeyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

take the

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *messageViewBottom;
```

is it IBOutlet of your view bottom constraint.

on keyboardwillshow

```
-(void)KeyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)keyboardInfo
{


        CGSize frame=[[[keyboardInfo valueForKey:@"userInfo"]valueForKey:@"UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"]CGRectValue].size;

        self.messageViewBottom.constant=frame.height; //add keyboard height to bottom constraint so your view go up when keyboard show




}
```

on keyboardhide

```
-(void)KeyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)keyboardInfo
{
    self.messageViewBottom.constant = 0;
}
```

i tink it will work for you :)